# ColorPicker not working

Tags: java, android

So basically I have a paint activty setup in my app which lets the user draw with a pen and also erase what they have done. However when i change the color of the pen it changes to white regardless of the color i've chosen and only the tips of the stroke are the correct color. Initially the color is set to black and works fine but when pen color is changed then the error happens.

P.s. when i change background color on canvas it changes correctly

**XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".DrawActivity"
>

<com.mukesh.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/scratch_pad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/size_layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save Image"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/load_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Load Image"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eraser_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Eraser"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/background_color_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Background Color"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pen_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pen"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pen_color_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pen Color"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/size_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:text="Pen Size"
        />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/pen_size_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:text="Eraser Size"
        />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/eraser_size_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**DrawActivity**

```
public class DrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private Button mSaveButton, mPenButton, mEraserButton, mPenColorButton, mBackgroundColorButton,
        mLoadButton;

private DrawingView mDrawingView;
private SeekBar mPenSizeSeekbar, mEraserSeekbar;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private ShakeEvent mShakeDetector;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);
    setTitle("Draw");
    initializeUI();
    setListeners();


    //shake feature to restart paint canvas

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeEvent();
    mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEvent.OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake(int count) {
            /*
             * The following method, "handleShakeEvent(count):" is a stub //
             * method you would use to setup whatever you want done once the
             * device has been shook.
             */

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(DrawActivity.this, "Paint canvas cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Add the following line to register the Session Manager Listener onResume
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // Add the following line to unregister the Sensor Manager onPause
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
    super.onPause();

}

private void setListeners() {
    mSaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPenButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mEraserButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPenColorButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBackgroundColorButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPenSizeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mEraserSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    mLoadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initializeUI() {
    mDrawingView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.scratch_pad);
    mSaveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    mLoadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.load_button);
    mPenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pen_button);
    mEraserButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eraser_button);
    mPenColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pen_color_button);
    mBackgroundColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.background_color_button);
    mPenSizeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.pen_size_seekbar);
    mEraserSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.eraser_size_seekbar);
}

@Override public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.save_button:
            mDrawingView.saveImage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "test",
                    Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);
            break;
        case R.id.load_button:
            mDrawingView.loadImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.image));
            Log.d("saveImage", "quality cannot better that 100");
            break;
        case R.id.pen_button:
            mDrawingView.initializePen();
            break;
        case R.id.eraser_button:
            mDrawingView.initializeEraser();
            break;
        case R.id.pen_color_button:
            final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(DrawActivity.this, 100, 100, 100);
            colorPicker.setCallback(
                    new ColorPickerCallback() {
                        @Override public void onColorChosen(int color) {
                            mDrawingView.setPenColor(color);
                            colorPicker.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            colorPicker.show();
            break;
        case R.id.background_color_button:
            final ColorPicker backgroundColorPicker = new ColorPicker(DrawActivity.this, 100, 100, 100);
            backgroundColorPicker.setCallback(
                    new ColorPickerCallback() {
                        @Override public void onColorChosen(int color) {
                            mDrawingView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                            backgroundColorPicker.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            backgroundColorPicker.show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    switch (seekBar.getId()) {
        case R.id.pen_size_seekbar:
            mDrawingView.setPenSize(i);
            break;
        case R.id.eraser_size_seekbar:
            mDrawingView.setEraserSize(i);
            break;
    }
}

@Override public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}

@Override public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}
}
```

Comment: If I had a debugger, I'd like to step into this method call: `mDrawingView.setPenColor(color);` and take a look at DrawingView. Please share all the relevant code snippets.

Comment: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length..... This is the error I am getting. I have tried using a different keyboard from Swiftkey which takes away this error however my initial problem persists